# htaccess to webconfig

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I am trying to run Candy XMPP webclient ( http://amiadogroup.github.com/candy/ ) under IIS. However, since it depends on RewriteRule in htaccess, I am unable to get it to login (I have already edited index.html to reflect the configuration on my XMPP server)

The htaccess of candy has only the following:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http-bind/ http://localhost:5280/http-bind/ [P]
```

I am new to IIS and don't know how to convert htaccess files to web.config

Comment: This will be tough to implement since 1) IIS does not support proxying requests just like that -- you will have to install [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) to add such functionality; 2) IIS does not have alternative for `Options +MultiViews` (at least I'm unaware of it).

Answer (score 0):

There's now a guide for IIS in the official Candy wiki: https://github.com/candy-chat/candy/wiki/HTTP-Proxy-Configuration#iis